# Django Cannot Assign Database Relation Error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-database

I have read many entries but couldn't find the answer. Here are my models:

```
class Branches(models.Model):
    branch_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.branch_name

class Agents(models.Model):
    branch_name = models.ForeignKey(Branches, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    agent_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.agent_name

class Policies(models.Model):
    policy_n = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    agent_name = models.ForeignKey(Agents, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    branch_name = models.ForeignKey(Branches, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

And the code that inserts data into related tables in my view.py file:

```
policies = pd.read_excel('policies.xlsx')

for i in policies.branches.unique():
    branch = Branches()
    branch.branch_name = i
    branch.save()

for j in policies.agents.unique():
    agent = Agents()
    agent.agent_name = j
    agent.save()

for i in range(len(policies)):
    policy = Policies()
    policy.policy_n = policies.policy_num[i]
    policy.account = policies.account[i]
    policy.branch_name = Branches.objects.get(branch_name=policies.branch[i])
    policy.agent_name = Agents.objects.get(agent_name=policies.agent_name[i])
```

I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "(<Branches: Copenhagen>,)": "Policies.branch_name" must be a "Branches" instance.
```

Can anybody help please.

Comment: could you please put all of your view code? I think some mistakes in your code (e.g. an additional comma) lead .get() method to return tuple object instead of Branchs object

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution! I converted the series object to list object and it is working now.

I changed the below lines from:

```
policy.branch_name = Branches.objects.get(branch_name=policies.branch[i])
policy.agent_name = Agents.objects.get(agent_name=policies.agent_name[i])
```

to:

```
policy.branch_name = Branches.objects.get(branch_name=list(policies.branch)[i])
policy.agent_name = Agents.objects.get(agent_name=policies.list(agent_name)[i])
```